Not logging to /opt folder using RHEL
I have a Django application that runs in a Docker container. I have a defaults.py file which defines the LOGGING configurations, I have included a file handler in the logging configuration to log to files.
‘file’: {‘class’: ‘logging.FileHandler’,
‘filename’: ‘/opt/tejcli/release/log/temp.log’,
‘formatter’: ‘simple’},

Above piece of code is the file handler that I have included. Unfortunately, no logs are being written to the temp.log, and not even a file is being created. I have manually created the tejcli/release/log folders. I wrote a Python script and put it in the home directory, tried writing logs to the same folder, and it worked. How do I solve this?


I have a Django application that runs in a Docker container.

Unless you've mounted the host /opt/tejcli/release/log/ to the container, the container's overlay filesystem will have its own internal /opt/tejcli/release/log/ directory, and the file will be there.
